# Android, retrieving things from JSONObject

Tags: php, android, json

I am trying to retrieve things from the database and I am programming on an Android.

Currently my setup is I have the database and have php files that process things from the database and return a `JSON` object. Then in my Android code I retrieve things from the `JSON` object.

So part of my code is this :

```
JSONObject jObject = null;
jObject = new JSONObject(result);
username = (String)jObject.get("uName");
```

This works fine when there is only 1 item under the `uName` that gets returned. However, lets say result has 3 things stored under `uName`. If I do the way I have been doing it, it will just return the first one.

Is there a way for me to return every single thing under the `uName`? If I do `jObject.get("uName");` more than once it still just returns the first entry

Comment: How would you generate such a `JSON`?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that `uName` is a JSONArray (For example: `{"uName":["Name1", "Name2"]}`) then you can do

```
JSONObject jObject = null;
jObject = new JSONObject(result);
JSONArray users = jObject.getJSONArray("uName");
```

Then, later on you can get a specific username by doing:

```
users.get(index);
```